# VB icon won't change in .exe

Tags: vb.net, debugging, icons, release

I have made a simple program that is pretty much useless but I have made it for practice to get some training. I have managed to set the icon that shows up when the program is running to the one I want but not the icon that appears when you highlight it in windows.

This image explains it.

http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/3329/myicons.jpg

So the icon that the arrow points at is the one that I want to be the same as the icons that ive marked with circles. I have tried to build this in debug and release mode but nothing fixes it. I have set the icon in 2 places shown below

http://pastebin.com/Wv8PpYh4

To avoid clogging up the page I added the 2 image links in pastebin

Thanks for any help!!! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the application icon in the application properties. Right click the project and choose properties or choose project propeties from the project menu.
The first option on the right is "application".

There is an option to set icon there

Comment: Look at the pictures, they are already set but it still won't work.

Comment: Ah, I missed the point that it was the exe selected. You have selected more than one file in that pic. Windows overlays the icons for multiple selections. If you select just the exe is it still the same? Also is it the same after rebuild?

Comment: I only selected that one exe. Also it is the same after rebuild both in release and debug.

Comment: Does it happen on any other application you compile or just this one?

Comment: Only this one I think, previous programs I have made in VB.net has only required me to set the icon in the form1 properties box.

Comment: Ok so I have tried some stuff on my code (nothing which was related to the icon) andrebooted my PC once. Now the icon shows perfectly. If someone else have this problem, try to transfer it onto a different PC and see if the problem still persist.

Comment: Windows has an icon cache so it doesn't have to reload every icon from the file every time. Therefore it often happens that changes to icons are not reflected immediately in all circumstances. There are ways to flush the cache however. See google.